# What's the difference between Kotlin object and class in the context of a dagger module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I was going through one of my colleagues codebase. And I found this piece of code.

```
@Module
object SampleAppModule {
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @AppScope
    fun provideAppDependency(context: Context): AppDependency = SampleAppDependency(context)
}
```

And this got me thinking, how's this different from this

```
@Module
class SampleAppModule {
    @Provides
    @AppScope
    fun provideAppDependency(context: Context): AppDependency = SampleAppDependency(context)
}
```

I've seen the use of object in dagger modules recently, but I myself never used it because I didn't understand what it does. Would love to get some insights.

p.s. I tried changing the object to class, and it worked. Now I really don't know if there is any difference.

Answer (score 4):

Using `object` to declare your Dagger modules would create only a single instance of it.

If your modules with `@Provides` are declared as `class` instead of `object`, then an additional object is generated on building the component. So using `object`, you get better performance.

Another way to do this would be using `companion object`. [But that is not recommended](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-410041915):

> Beyond that, don't use `companion object` for modules. Use `object`. In
> that case the instance will be unused and its initialization code will
> be removed by R8 and the methods will be truly static and can also be
> inlined just like Java.

Comment: Alright, can't we get around the part of single instance, by making the module a Singleton?

I might be wrong here b/w.

Comment: You would require a scope even if the module was an `object` or a `class`. It is just modules with `class` generate an additional object when they're built, than `object` modules.

Comment: What is **it** in `a single instance of it.`? I suppose you meant the module itself. From what I can understand you mean dagger would anyways convert the module class to a singleton object of the module which improves the performance.